# Create/Add Marker to Google Map when Inside of Street View Panorama

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am using the Google Map Javascript API and am wondering how I can add a marker to the map while inside of the street view.

When I am overviewing a road, I want to be able to go into Street View, then click on a spot and add a marker to where I click. So far I am not able to find any documentation or help on this matter. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

The click event which is present on the map, does not fire inside the street view. Is there another function? The draggable markers are draggable in street view. So how do I trigger a click to add a marker?

Answer (score 0):

## It is not currently possible to add a marker while inside a Street View through click events

Here's the list of [events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewEvents) that are available for `StreetViewPanorama`:

- `pano_changed`
- `position_changed`
- `pov_changed`
- `links_changed`
- `visible_changed`

As you can see, there's no mention of `click` event. So it would obviously not be available. And the `click` is only available in the `Map` class and not in the `StreetViewPanorama` class. They are two different classes, so you should set your expectation that they have different functionalities and eventListeners.

The `StreetViewPanorama` class also have this built in click function where it makes you move to the next position of the streetview path.

There could also be a lot of factors as to why this is not available in the Street View, like how would the StreetView know which coordinate in the Map was clicked inside the Street View **Image**?

But you can still file a Feature Request if you want and make sure to add your use case. https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker

The reason also why you can still click and drag marker around inside a `StreetView` is because the `Marker` class is also a different class with Map and StreetViewPanorama. If you add an event Listener or make the **marker** draggable, it would ofcourse still have those functionality regardless if it is inside the Map or the Street View.

I hope this clarifies your concern!